# Running flutter/dart tests in AOT/release or profile mode?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, flutter, dart

If I understand it correctly by default `flutter test` will run with a JIT on the Dart VM, while the release mode uses an AOT compiler to native code.
I (think to) have a crash which only happens in AOT mode (release and profile), and it would be way easier to debug and reproduce it when I could isolate it by running code in AOT/profile mode.

So how can I run tests (or at least code snippets) in AOT mode? (I don't really care if it runs on an actual iOS or Android device, or is executed on the dev machine or simulators.

(I have found [an article which seems to describe the compilation process](https://thosakwe.com/aot-compilation-and-other-dart-hackery/), but is pretty involved. Is there some easier way for tests?)

Comment: Instead of `flutter test` you may want `flutter drive`

Comment: I'd rather run individual unit tests, than integration tests, also are you sure that `flutter drive` would use AOT compiled code to run?

Comment: Yes, there's an option on `flutter drive` for that: `--profile`

Answer (score 1):

I have found a rather simple solution which is [documented on the dart website](https://dart.dev/tools/dart2aot). Starting with Dart 2.3 there is a `dart2aot` and `dartaotruntime` bundled with the SDK. This allows simple execution and I was able to reproduce my crash.

```
Herbys-MacBook-Pro-2017:migrate$ dart2aot migrate_aot_test.dart migrate_aot_test.dart.aot
Herbys-MacBook-Pro-2017:migrate$ dartaotruntime migrate_aot_test.dart.aot
[...]

===== CRASH =====
si_signo=Segmentation fault: 11(11), si_code=1, si_addr=0x1061000410f
Abort trap: 6
Herbys-MacBook-Pro-2017:migrate$
```

Comment: Please report a bug at dartbug.com with a reproduction. We will take a look. Thanks!

Comment: @VyacheslavEgorov thanks, actually just did that :-) https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/37656