# How to run test in release mode

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-release, dart-test

I had a bug on a Flutter project I'm working on that was only happening in release mode.

When running the application with

```bash
flutter run
```

everything was working fine.

The bug was only there with

```bash
flutter run --release
```

I would want to write a test about the fix. How do I run the test in release mode?

I don't see an option `--release` that I could use with `flutter test`

Comment: ``flutter drive`` ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57215822/running-flutter-dart-tests-in-aot-release-or-profile-mode